# Matplotlib fails with `TypeError` when plotting with mpmath

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, mpmath

I have 2D data which is very small (of order `e-500`) so I cannot use numpy which I would like to draw as a pcolormesh. For instance,

```
import mpmath as mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpmath import e as e
from mpmath import mpf, mpc,mp
mp.dps = 1000
y, x = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000), np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000))
z = e ** (-x**2 + y)
z = z[:-1, :-1]
z_min, z_max = -np.abs(z).max(), np.abs(z).max()
```

compiles very well but when I want to do a `pcolormesh` things go south:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
c = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap='RdBu', vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)
ax.set_title('Titles are overall a positive feature')
ax.axis([x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

gives the error `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Why does this happen? Do you have any idea how to solve this? Maybe plotting without mpmath can be helpful.

**EDIT:** Full traceback

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
   339                 pass
   340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
   342             # Finally look for special method names
   343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
   246 
   247     if 'png' in formats:
--> 248         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
   249     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
   250         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
   130         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
   131 
--> 132     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
   133     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
   134     if fmt == 'svg':

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
  2077                             print_method, dpi=dpi, orientation=orientation),
  2078                         draw_disabled=True)
-> 2079                     self.figure.draw(renderer)
  2080                     bbox_artists = kwargs.pop("bbox_extra_artists", None)
  2081                     bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    36                 renderer.start_filter()
    37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    39         finally:
    40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
  1733 
  1734             self.patch.draw(renderer)
-> 1735             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  1736                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  1737 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
   135     if not_composite or not has_images:
   136         for a in artists:
--> 137             a.draw(renderer)
   138     else:
   139         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    36                 renderer.start_filter()
    37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    39         finally:
    40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
  2628             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
  2629 
-> 2630         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  2631 
  2632         renderer.close_group('axes')

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
   135     if not_composite or not has_images:
   136         for a in artists:
--> 137             a.draw(renderer)
   138     else:
   139         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    36                 renderer.start_filter()
    37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    39         finally:
    40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in draw(self, renderer)
  2045                 offsets = np.column_stack([xs, ys])
  2046 
-> 2047         self.update_scalarmappable()
  2048 
  2049         if not transform.is_affine:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in update_scalarmappable(self)
   790             return
   791         if self._is_filled:
--> 792             self._facecolors = self.to_rgba(self._A, self._alpha)
   793         elif self._is_stroked:
   794             self._edgecolors = self.to_rgba(self._A, self._alpha)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py in to_rgba(self, x, alpha, bytes, norm)
   243         if norm:
   244             x = self.norm(x)
--> 245         rgba = self.cmap(x, alpha=alpha, bytes=bytes)
   246         return rgba
   247 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py in __call__(self, X, alpha, bytes)
   559         if np.ma.is_masked(X):
   560             mask_bad = X.mask
--> 561         elif np.any(np.isnan(X)):
   562             # mask nan's
   563             mask_bad = np.isnan(X)

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

<Figure size 432x288 with 2 Axes> ```
````

Comment: full traceback, please!

Comment: @hpaulj added. Thank you.

Comment: what is `z.dtype`?  Why are you using `mpmath`?

Comment: @hpaulj I have 2D data which is of varied small scales (so for instance there can be some of it which is `e-100` and  some which is `e-500`). Python (or more precisely `numpy` are not sufficient for this purpose) so I had to turn to `mpmath`. Then I wish to visualize this data as a heatmap.

Comment: @hpaulj before we rush to close, do you have any idea how to plot my small data?

Answer (score 0):

With your code, edited to run in reasonable testing time:

```
    ...: mp.dps = 10
    ...: y, x = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 10), np.linspace(-5, 5, 10))
    ...: z = e ** (-x**2 + y)
    ...: z = z[:-1, :-1]
    ...: z_min, z_max = -np.abs(z).max(), np.abs(z).max()
    ...: 
In [11]: z
Out[11]: 
array([[mpf('9.357622969874e-14'), mpf('2.842594865759e-13'),
        mpf('8.635040754285e-13'), mpf('2.623093769921e-12'),
        mpf('7.968255300282e-12'), mpf('2.420542233701e-11'),
        mpf('7.352958062098e-11'), mpf('2.233631436379e-10'),
        mpf('6.785173193566e-10')],
...., dtype=object)
In [12]: z.dtype
Out[12]: dtype('O')
In [13]: np.isnan(z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-13-72670087bbfa>", line 1, in <module>
    np.isnan(z)
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

By using `mpmath` you have created a object dtype array.  While that may have greater precision, it also runs much slower, and in some cases does not run at all.

`isnan` expects a numeric dtype array:

```
In [16]: np.any(np.isnan(z.astype(float)))
Out[16]: False
```

The traceback indicates that `plot` uses the `isnan` to "blank out" `nan` values in the plot.

This works:

```
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z.astype('float128'), cmap='RdBu', vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)
```

Comment: Casting to `float128` causes the plot to the 0 in almost every pixel.

Comment: That's better than producing an error :(  I don't see how pushing the precision helps, but I've only played a bit with tis plot.  Changing the plot and calculation ranges do more to make the plot interesting.